# How to make header fit to the screen window?

Tags: html, css

What I have is a header and background image to that header.

Here is my code:

```
header{
    background-image: url(/img/ffHeader.png);
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0 0 15%;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }
```

With the above code, I am getting my image shrink automatically as per the window size but I am not able to get the header. It seems same what should I do that the header should also increase and decrease as per the window size. I have tried to give height 100% but it’s not working it gets my header to approx 100px.

The header size should also be re-size as per the window size?
How can I get this?

I am trying to add a menu in header my code is as below

```
<header>
        <button id='login'>Login</button>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#myleague">MY LEAGUES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#myscore">MY SCORES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#leaderboard">LEADERBOARD</a></li>
                <li><a href="#howtoplay">HOW TO PLAY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">RULES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">SUPPORT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</header>

        nav ul{
            list-style: none;
        }
        nav ul li{
            margin: 0 auto;
            float: left;
            padding-top: 7%;
        }
```

The code above makes me reach to the just 5px above the end of the image, but it’s not being resized with the header. What can be the problem?

Comment: You mean the height of the header? Try height: 100vh;

Comment: will it automatically increase and decrease?

Comment: its like a box that should be resized..I need that to my header

Comment: yes. 100vh means 100% of viewport height (vh) this means the header will always be as big as your screen. Similarly you can use 100vw (viewport width) to make it as wide as the browser window

Comment: I still have no idea what you're asking. Could you edit your question to include your extra details?

Comment: @Pureferret i wanted to cerate a header that will automatically resize as per the size of a window

Comment: Height, width? How much height/width? It's unclear what you're getting as you say "but I am not able to get the header", but I don't what you want the Header to do...does it not appear, is it not the full width/height? How do you know this? Could you give pictures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to replace height with padding bottom to make height respond to the width of the page.

```
header{
        background-image: url(/img/ffHeader.png);
        width: 100%;
        height: 0;
        padding: 0 0 40%;
        border: 1px solid;
        background-size: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
     }
```

Comment: You'll need to adjust the padding bottom to fit your site, try 20%... Just adjust the 40% to fit!

Comment: I have added menu in that Header how can it will also resize as per the window size? I am trying to put list and giving the margin -top 7% but it is not resizing with header? how to get that?

Comment: @SandhyaGor you'll need to post a new question for that to be answered

Answer (score 1):

You should Change Your HTML and CSS structure

```
<div class='header_box'>
   <div class='header'>
   </div>
</div>


.header_box{

    background-image: url(/img/ffHeader.png);
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;       
 }


   .header
   {
    height: auto;
    width:80%;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

   }
```

Comment: add width:80% to header class

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<style>
.header{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        padding: 0;
        border: 1px solid;
        background-size: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
     }

.header_image{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
     </style>

<div class="header">
    <img src = "/img/ffHeader.png" class="header_image" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with jquery and resize function

like this:

```
var width=window.innerWidth;
function resiz_header_height(){
var height = (window.innerWidth * 200) / width;
$('.header').css('min-height', height + 'px');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
resiz_header_height();
$(window).resize(resiz_header_height);
});
```